# Git client that can handle and organize a large number of repos

Tags: windows, git, version-control

I have over 50 git repos to manage. Some are for work, some are personal. I am looking for a git client app that has some way to organize all these repos, and which is preferably open source or at least not tied to some service. Platform is mainly Windows, but Linux support would be nice.

I need to flick between repos fast.

**Github Desktop**: Lists repos alphabetically, no organizing features.

**Sourcetree**: No organizing features, many clicks to switch repo.

**TortoiseGit**: Terrible UI, many clicks to switch repo.

**GitKraken**: Requires an account, no organizing.

**SmartGit**: Organizing by single level groups, fast repo switching, non-free.

**GitExtensions**: No organizing, many clicks to switch repo.

**Tower**: Expensive but seems to do what I need.

**gitg**: No organizing, many clicks to switch repo.

**git-cola**: No organizing, many clicks to switch repo.

**GitAhead**: No organizing, many clicks to switch repo.

**GitEye**: No organizing, many clicks to switch repo.

Here's an example of organizing repos into a more manageable list, from SmartGit:

[image: organized repos]

Comment: As a user of gitcola, I don't understand the argument given. You can chose between seeing a list of last-used repos, a list of your favorite repos (see the screenshot on [their homepage](https://git-cola.github.io/), or both. One (double?) click to switch repos that way. Did you miss that feature?

Comment: what is wrong with the command line? 0 clicks all of the time.

Comment: @Izzy I tried Git-Cola. It wouldn't run on my machine, no error message just no window. It looks like it might be usable if I can get it going. Does it support folders for organizing favourite repos?

Comment: Works fine for me (on Linux). Didn't try with folders, as I didn't see that feature announced. I rarely use favorites; I rather call gitcola from CLI while inside the repo :) // @SteveBarnes Guess a GUI is preferred here, though not specified (OP might wish to add the `gui` tag to confirm).