# git client collecting repositories, organize and update

Tags: linux, git, version-control

**What I need**

A git client to organize a collection of git repositories. I want to organize them into different topics and a visual representation for repo name and short description, if available (similar to *trending repos* in some smartphone apps). Details like branches, history, statistics is not needed. A local clone is optional.

It is not meant to be used for development.

**Currently what I am doing**

Using bash shell to clone a list of repositories, organize in different folders.

**Problem**

- missing overview with short description of repo
- slow, needs redesign

The recommendation [for a similar problem is git-cola](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45203/44571). It does not suit my purpose, though, because there is not sufficient overview with repo description.

**Minimum requirements:**

- Linux OS
- free
- lightweight

Comment: when in need of a GUI, I use Git Cola. It's available from the Linux repos (package `git-cola`). It lists the last used repos (well, of course it does much more). Maybe you take a look at that while waiting for better recommendations? // PS: [here are some answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=git+cola+is%3Aa) recommending Git Cola, for a pre-install check :)

Comment: That's why I made it a comment only – I'm aware it doesn't fit completely, but might be an "interim solution" until a "real one" gets recommended.